# Issue with Datepicker UI and Highcharts and the dateFormat

Tags: jquery, highcharts, datepicker, date-format

for some reason my datepicker UI doesn't respect the date format after selecting a date. For example if i choose 03-11.2006, when i press enter, suddenly it change to 11-03-2006.

I don't know if the problem is with the datepicker dateformat, or with the highchart dateformat.

You can see a example in this link http://www.cartesio.com/cartesio14/english/fondo_cartesio_y.asp

I will appreciate any help.

Sorry for my terrible English.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving the datepicker and highcharts conflicting date formats.

Datepicker is expecting '01-01-2014' (dd-mm-yy) while highcharts is placing in values as '01-JAN-14' (%d-%b-%y).

My *guess* would be the datepicker fails to parse those highcharts dates, and you really want to initialize the datepicker to 'dd-M-y' which matches highcharts.